# Install Visual C# Express 2010 onto client machines - redistributable package needed

Tags: installation, windows, msi, visual-studio

I would like to install Visual C# Express 2010 onto several machines on the Windows network at the school where I work. I can only find web and ISO installers, but I really need MSIs for both Visual C# and its dependencies to perform managed installs. Any ideas how to get hold of these, or how to get around this problem?

(To clarify, I am not the network admin. I asked them and they said this was the problem, so I apologise if I've stated it incorrectly or info is missing. Hopefully all makes sense.)

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio is not something which can be installed via MSI.  See [MSDN for the supported mechanism for administrative installs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225237.aspx) of Visual Studio.  I believe VS Express uses the same bootstrapper, and should work similarly.